# Effort issue when testing

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing

I have been reading on using Effort for unit testing due to how "easy" it is to setup a database in memory. I have been trying to implement this in my test data service but I keep running into issues. 
I am using Entity Framework 6 and models that were generated from existing tables.

**Context Model**

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities()
        : base("name=Entities")
    {
    }

    //Overloading for effort unit test
    public Entities(DbConnection connection) : base(connection,true)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<REPAIR_CHECK_IN_TABLE> REPAIR_CHECK_IN_TABLEs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<tblPlanarWarranty> tblPlanarWarranties { get; set; }
}
```

**Test DataService**

```
private IDataLoader loader;
    private Entities context;


    public TestDataService()
    {

        loader = new Effort.DataLoaders.CsvDataLoader(@"_TestDataFiles\");
        context = new Entities(Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient(loader));
    }
```

Initially I would get the following error.

> No entity Framework provider for the ADO.NET provider withe invariant name 'Effort.Provider'

I then added said provider to my provider section of the app config file and started receiving this error.

> The 'Instance' member of the entity Framework provider type 'Effort.ProviderServices,Effort,Version-1.0.0.0 didt not return an object that inherits from 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DBProviderServices'

Does anyone have some insight as to what I am doing wrong? On the site it was as easy as a few lines but this has turned into a huge mess.

Comment: Well your Effort.ProviderServices class doesn't inherit from System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DBProviderServices?  I think the error is pretty clear

Comment: This is true, I am more concerned with how to implement this correctly as here is all I have to work with. https://effort.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Create%20a%20fake%20DbContext%20instance&referringTitle=Tutorials

Comment: Are you using the Effort.EF6 version? Comment from your link: `After I did this I was able to get the sample to work using EF6, "Effort.EF6" library from nuget (as distinct from "Effort" without the EF6) and using a Database First approach.`

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick you are my hero! I wish I could mark as answer but not enough points yet. Thanks for pointing that out, I completely overlooked the other nugut package.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful! When using EF6 don't install **Effort by ZZZ Projects**!

Install **Effort.EF6** by the same ZZZ projects

```
class SchoolDbContext : DbContext
{
    // the standard constructors you probably already use:
    public SchooldDbContext() : base(...) {}
    public SchoolDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString) {}

    // add this one for effort:
    public SchoolDbContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection) 
        : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection) { }

    ... // DbSets, etc
```

### Use clean empty database

```
var dbConnection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();
using (var dbContext = new SchoolDbContext(dbConnection, true)
{
      dbContext.Schools.Add(new School {...});
      dbConext.SaveChanges();

      // this database exists as long as the connection exists
      var schoolCount = dbContext.Schools.Count();
      // expect one school
}

// a new empty database will be created: there won't be any schools
dbConnection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();
using (var dbContext = new SchoolDbContext(dbConnection)
{
     var schoolCount = dbContext.Schools.Count();
     // expect no schools
}
```

### Reuse the database

this database will be persisted for the time of your program. The model will be creade only once.

```
const string dbName = "MyDb"
var dbConnection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePersistent(dbName);
using (var dbContext = new SchoolDbContext(dbConnection)
{
      dbContext.Schools.Add(new School {...});
      dbContext.SaveChanges();
}

dbConnection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePersistent(dbName);
using (var dbContext = new SchoolDbContext(dbConnection)
{
     var schoolCount = dbContext.Schools.Count();
     // expect the school you just added
}
```